# Which yajna was performed by Prajapati Daksha?

Tags: shiva, yajna, daksha

Which yajna was it which was performed by Prajapati Daksha in which he didn't invite Lord Shiva and suffered with consecutive events ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Which yajna was it which was performed by Prajapati Daksha in which he didn't invite Lord Shiva ?

The answer is provided in [**Mahabharata-Shanti Parva**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b110.htm)-Moksha Dharma Parva- Chapter-283 , where this story of Daksha yajna is narriated by Maharshi  Veda Vyasa.
When Goddess Uma came to know about all the gods leaving for Daksha Prajapatis yajna , she was curious and asked lord Shiva about that. Then Lord Mahadeva himself answered to Devi Uma that Daksha prajapati is performing Ashwamedha yajna. Following is the shloka of that conversation.

> महेश्वर उवाच
>
> दक्षो नाम महाभागो प्रजानां पतिरुत्तम : |
>  हयमेधेन
> यजते तत्र यान्ति दिवौकस: || 24 ||
>
> P. 311 - Maheswara said, 'O lady that art highly blessed, the
> excellent Prajapati Daksha is adoring the gods in a **Horse-sacrifice.**
> These denizens of heaven are proceeding even thither.

---

So  Daksha Prajapati was performing Ashwamdha yajna at the time , when devi Uma asked Mahadeva about the Yajna and why he is not invited to the Yajna .

Here is [**Hindi Translation**](https://archive.org/details/MahabharatYear3Vol.1GitaPressGorakhpur/page/n379) with Shlokas.

[image]

Comment: Even in Shiva Purana which version I have, it is nowhere mentioned which yajna was it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto haha yes , the story is mentioned in many puranas as well , but even i haven't seen the name of the Yajna in them . But then i turned towards MB and found it over there. BTW grt. question Keep it up.

Comment: Which Version of Shiva Purana you have. Motilal Banarasidas one ? There are two versions available at archieve.org. One is with sanskrit shlokas and another is without.Here is one - https://archive.org/details/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1

Comment: And here is another one. https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-01/topic-1 May be you are already aware of both but i am just giving the links in case...

Comment: BTW another thing is ,  In Mahabhrata the  event of Sati casting her body is not mentioned. It is only present in Puranas i think.

Comment: I have the one shared by TheDestroyer. Thanks for the link, will check them later.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the Yajna is called "Devi Yajna".

As per Devi Bhagavatam:

> He is not to return any more. He who bathes in all the Tîrthas and
>   makes a journey round the whole world, gets Nirvâna. He is not reborn.
>   He who performs the Horse-Sacrifice in this holy land Bhârata enjoys
>   half the Indraship for as many years as there are hairs on the body of
>   the horse. He who performs a Râjasûya Sacrifice, gets four times the
>   above result. **Of all the sacrifices, the Devî Yajñâ, or the Sacrifice
>   before the Devî is the Best.** O Fair One! Of old, Visnu, Brahmâ, Indra
>   and when Tripurâsura was killed, Mahâ Deva did such a sacrifice. O
>   Beautiful One! This sacrifice before the S’akti is the highest and
>   best of all the sacrifices. There is nothing like this in the three
>   worlds. **This Great Sacrifice was done of yore by Daksa when he
>   collected abundant sacrificial materials of all sorts. And a quarrel
>   ensued on this account between Daksa and S’ankara. The Brâhmins
>   conducting the sacrifice cursed the Nandî and others. And Nandî cursed
>   the Brâhmanas. Mahâdeva, therefore, disallowed the going on of
>   sacrifice and brought it to a dead stop**. Of yore the Prajâpati Daksa
>   did this Devî Yajñâ; it was done also by Dharma, Kas’yapa; Ananta,
>   Kardama, Svâyambhuva Manu, his son Priyavrata, S’iva, Sanat Kumâra,
>   Kapila and Dhruva
>
> **Book 9, Chapter 30**

Therefore, it is the Devi Yajna which Daksha was performing and which was eventually destroyed by Lord Shiva's troops.